javascript_importmap_tags is creating a link to "application.js" with error
I am working on adding javascript handling to a rails 7 app. I want to use import maps to import external libraries for turbo and stimulus. The current issue I'm having trouble with is that javascript_importmap_tags is adding an unusable link to my application:
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/application.js">

This gives me this error :
GET http://localhost:3000/application.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I have an application.js file in app/javascript. I don't understand why the call to javascript_importmap_tags is creating a link to a nonexistent javascript file at the application root. I think I must be missing a step somewhere. What do I need to do to make the application.js file load?
This is my importmap.rb file:
pin "application"

and my application.js file is currently just comments:
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails

// import "stimulus.min.js"
// import "stimulus-loading.js"
// import "controllers"
// import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"

Please feel free to look at the source for the application here:
https://github.com/fredwillmore/climate-control

config.load_defaults 5.2 but you're using rails 7. config.api_only = true why, looks like you're making a full app. also, you're missing sprockets-rails gem.

@Alex good point - I am adapting a project I started in rails 5.2. I had originally intended for it to be a rails backend with a React frontend, but now I want to use Hotwire. I also want to use importmaps instead of sprockets.

importmaps and sprockets are not mutually exclusive you need both. importmap-rails or jsbundling-rails. sprockets-rails or propshaft.

I'm looking here: https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/guide-to-rails-7-and-the-asset-pipeline/80851 and it says importmaps "replaces Sprockets as the default asset pipeline gem". So I would prefer not to depend on Sprockets if possible. However it's very possible that I still have some vestigial dependency on it. But I can't find any references to sprockets in my code.

importmaps replaces Sprockets as the default asset pipeline gem - that's 100% incorrect, even some people in that thread are saying it. importmaps only handle javascript, like sass for css. you still need something to actually serve these assets - sprockets.

Ok so I think I misunderstood the role of import-maps - is this a good explanation of my problem: sprockets is no longer a part of Rails by default, but if I want to create a full app (not just API), I will still need sprockets to handle the assets, including those imported with import-maps
